# Is "Functional Analysis" by "Yosida" a good book for self study?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, self-learning

I was wishing to start studying by myself the book [Functional Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540586547) by [Yosida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dsaku_Yosida), does anyone have already used it, is it a good reference?

Comment: You haven't any answers to most of your questions. Please consider going through them and accepting some if you find'em satisfying.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip =D

Comment: How do I accept them?

Comment: You have accepted some. To accept an answer hover your mouse just below the downvote button to the answer you want to accept. A *check* sign will appear. To accept it just click on the check sign. When it turns green you've accepted the answer.

Comment: In fact, I had already done it some times, thanks =D

Comment: and how about Yosida's book?

Comment: No problem. I wouldn't know about that book or any Functional Analysis book for that matter, sorry. Hopefully someone else will help you.

Comment: Hauah, ok, thanks anyway ^^

Comment: No. It is too advanced for beginner

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yosida's book is excellent, but certainly not easy reading. It was absolutely cutting edge when it was first published and the style is demanding. I would only recommend it as second or third reading in functional analysis after having achieved a pretty solid background. In addition, some people complain about difficulties understanding the sometimes slightly outdated terminology.

On the positive side, Yosida contains many results and examples that are otherwise hard to find. This is one of the reasons that it still is a widely used reference book which has stood its test of time. Familiarity with it can't hurt...

Since your previous questions indicate that you are relatively new to functional analysis, I would recommend to read something easier going and maybe more modern. You might enjoy [Lax's book](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471556041.html) or [Stein and Shakarchi](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9627.html) or [Reed and Simon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125850506). See also

- [Good book for self study of functional analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/good-book-for-self-study-of-functional-analysis)
- [An introductory textbook on functional analysis and operator theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164127/an-introductory-textbook-on-functional-analysis-and-operator-theory)

for further recommendations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips =D Indeed I am new to functional analysis, I have just taken a first course in functional analysis using the book "Introductory functional analysis" by Irvin Kreyszig, and I guess it was a nice course, and I want to try something more advanced now, and by what you told me Yosida is gonna be a hard but good choice =D But I'll check those other books too..I didn't know Stein had a book about functional analysis, his exposition's style is great, I guess that must be a nice book..

Comment: Well, you can always give it a try... Only you can decide whether Yosida suits your taste and needs. It's a big step from Kreyszig to Yosida, so don't be discouraged and pick a book of intermediate level if progress is slower than expected. There's a wide variety of good books out there and Yosida surely is among the tougher general texts. // Yes, Stein and Shakarchi's book is a fantastic conclusion of their analysis book series.

Comment: I agree =D Thanks for the help again..